# How to disable trailing swipe on UITableView Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe

How to ignore the right to left swipe or the Trailing swipe, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
        return swipeAction
    }
```